# Copy from ansible empty folder on remote server

Tags: linux, ansible

I use ansible for install and setting aplication on linux server.

I can not copy empty folder on remote server.

For example.
I have a folder

> test

that contains:

> 123.conf
>
> log

log is empty folder

I try copy use ansible:

```
 - name: Copy config test
   copy: src=/home/user/test/ dest=/tmp/test
```

After executing the script on remote server copied only file 123.conf
If into folder log create file then copied normal.

How copy empty folder use ansible?

Comment: Add some hidden file in log folder, like `.placeholder` or just create that folder with `file` module. I looks that Ansible can't track empty folders.

Comment: may still create archive and copy then unarhive

Comment: Ansible 2.4.3.0 copies empty directories. What version do you use?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS ansible 1.5.4

Answer (score 2):

- The version of Ansible you're using, 1.5, is 4 years old.
- The more recent Ansible 2.4.3.0 copies empty directories

Therefore the solution is: upgrade Ansible.

(content migrated from comments [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49382479/copy-from-ansible-empty-folder-on-remote-server#comment85768792_49382479) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49382479/copy-from-ansible-empty-folder-on-remote-server#comment85772188_49382479))

Comment: I'm using ansible 2.9, it has the same issue.